# How to use config.json file for Hugging Face transformer model loading from Google Cloud Storage (GCS)?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, pytorch, google-cloud-storage, huggingface-transformers

I'd like to be able to load a Hugging Face transformer base (xlm-roberta-base) from GCS. However when loading using the pytorch_model.bin file, it requires a directory containing config.json file to be given as argument. However obviously GCS buckets do not act like regular directories. How can I achieve this?

So far what I have attempted is something like this:

```
    fs = gcsfs.GCSFileSystem(project="{project_name}")
    XLMRobertaModel.from_pretrained(fs.cat("{bucket}/xlm-roberta-base/pytorch_model.bin"), 
        from_pt=True, config=fs.cat("{bucket}/xlm-roberta-base/config.json"))
```

This produces error message:

OSError: Can't load the configuration of '<File-like object GCSFileSystem, bucket/xlm-roberta-base/config.json>'. If you were trying to load it from 'https://huggingface.co/models', make sure you don't have a local directory with the same name. Otherwise, make sure '<File-like object GCSFileSystem, bucket/xlm-roberta-base/config.json>' is the correct path to a directory containing a config.json file

I know fs.cat("{bucket}/xlm-roberta-base/config.json") is not going to return a path to a directory, but I'm not sure what I should give as argument given the directory is in a GCS bucket.

Is it possible to do this at all?